# Marklogic search:search Total Results vs Actual Results

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to do a search in Marklogic using the `search:search` API.

```
let $q := "Foo ^ Bar"
let $start := 0
let $page-length := 10

search:search($q ,$config:SEARCH-OPTIONS ,$start ,$page-length)
```

where `$config:SEARCH-OPTIONS` is a bunch of search options.

I have two records in my database, but the above query should only return one.

Now when I search I get 1 match. However, I get a result total of 2. This is wrong, then I applied the “unfiltered” setting to the query and there are two matches. However, why is it that a filtered query gives me back a count of the BEFORE filtered results, giving me a total that is incorrect?

Is there a way to ask Marklogic to instead give the actual count? `fn:count` works if you return every result, but if you are using paging, this obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your content? How do your two records look like, and how are they stored? As separate documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the search API will not do what you want. The only way to get a 100% accurate count is to do an `fn:count` of the filtered query results. Not too time consuming if your case of two results, but prohibitive if your search returned millions of documents. This is why, internally, the search api uses xdmp:estimate and can't be configured to do otherwise.

The usual way of solving this problem is with messaging and UI; make sure your UI talks about approximate result counts, and don't let the pagination controls take the user too far into the result set in one jump, in case it takes them beyond the end. Google is a good example of this approach.

At the other end of the scale, I've had success with simply examining the search API's count estimate, and replacing it with the output of `fn:count` if the **result-set** looks small enough that users might notice the discrepancy between the estimate and the actual count (as in your example.) In that case, the cost of `fn:count` should be low.

You didn't ask explicitly so you may know this, but the reason the estimate is wrong in this case is very likely that you include punctuation in you query string, which results in a query that can't be resolved from indexes alone (I assume that both your documents contain the words "Foo" and "Bar", and that the differentiating factor is that only one of them contains "^"?). If your application allows for excluding that option then it would give you much more reliable estimates.

A last resort option, if you are sure your result sets will always be small, is to bypass the search API entirely and call `cts:search` directly. You'd then be free to run your own `fn:count` on the results and paginate them however you like. You can either build a `cts:query` programatically yourself, or use the search:parse function to generate the cts query that the search api would use internally, and simply pass it to `cts:search` yourself.

Comment: That's for the great reply. The first result gives me a score back, the second gives me this back score="0" confidence="0" fitness="0" - would punctuation cause this?

Comment: I don't think so, no. Scores are calculated based on index, before filtering, so results in the unfiltered result-set should have a score. Scoring is pretty mysterious to me though and there are lot of factors that can influence it; I'd do some reading about document scores and query weights.

Comment: Note: the total returned by Search API is not necessarily inaccurate. As mblakele sais, you can choose fragmentation and indexes such that the estimate is accurate. Reverting to fn:count will have great impact on performance and scalability..

Answer (score 2):

> why is it that a filtered query gives me back a count of the BEFORE filtered results?

Because the total is based on `xdmp:estimate` or `cts:remainder`, which always return an unfiltered count of fragments that match the query in the indexes. The docs at http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/count_estimate discuss this topic: "Effectively, xdmp:estimate puts the decision to optimize counting through use of the indexes in the hands of the developer."

You can use `fn:count` instead of `xdmp:estimate` or `cts:remainder` - but then your application will perform O(n) with the total number of results. Usually the best strategy is to use `xdmp:estimate` or `cts:remainder`, but arrange the document structure and database indexes so that the estimate is accurate.

Comment: http://docs.marklogic.com/search:search says:  "The value of the total attribute is an estimate, based on the index resolution of the query, and it is not filtered for accuracy."